# Million of close syscalls on LXD container when run a command from Python and sh module

Tags: python, linux, containers, lxd

I have a Python application where I uses the Python **sh** module multiple times to run commands. Also, I use **LXD** containers to run isolated tests.

I noticed a very different performance running my tests on LXD container, so I started to reduce the complexity of the Python script.

Now the scrip is a simple **sh.nice()** but there is heavy difference between the host and the lxc container.

Host

```
$ time python -c "import sh; sh.nice()"
real    0m0.077s
user    0m0.052s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Container

```
$ time python -c "import sh; sh.nice()"
real    0m0.215s
user    0m0.088s
sys     0m0.120s
```

My next step was use strace which says that the container version calls the syscall `close` 1,048,796 times!! The majority of the times it returns EBADF (Bad file descriptor).

Here is what I have done; what's happening?

```
$ uname -a
Linux cmp-1 4.4.0-96-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 12 14:59:54 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lxc launch ubuntu:precise new-precise-sh
$ lxc exec new-precise-sh -- bash
$ apt-get install python-pip
$ pip install sh
$ strace -f -e close python -c "import sh; sh.nice()" 2>&1 | wc -l
1048796
```

Running strace with output in different files. There is one too big **strace.2618**

```
$ strace -ff -o strace python -c "import sh; sh.nice()"
$ ls -la
total 75276
drwxrwxr-x  2 user   user       4096 Sep 27 16:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 41 user   user       4096 Sep 27 16:45 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     121780 Sep 27 16:33 strace.2615
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root       3995 Sep 27 16:33 strace.2616
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root       6108 Sep 27 16:33 strace.2617
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   76558803 Sep 27 16:33 strace.2618
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root     362363 Sep 27 16:33 strace.2619
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      10748 Sep 27 16:33 strace.2620
```

The content of the file something like this:

```
$ cat strace.2618
...................
...................
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024*1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(5)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(6)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(7)                                = 0
close(8)                                = 0
close(9)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(10)                               = 0
close(11)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
...................
...................
close(33)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(34)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(35)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(36)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(37)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(38)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
...................
...................
close(1048568)                          = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1048569)                          = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1048570)                          = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1048571)                          = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1048572)                          = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1048573)                          = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1048574)                          = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(1048575)                          = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
```

Comment: Python will try to close all fds from third up to maximum (which is usually a ulimit for file descriptors): https://github.com/certik/python-2.7/blob/c360290c3c9e55fbd79d6ceacdfc7cd4f393c1eb/Lib/subprocess.py#L1097 Consider reducing soft-limits via `/etc/security/limits.conf` (depends on distro)

Comment: Thanks!!
Here is the reason, https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3860. sh module is who is closing all the file descriptors in lxd container where the limit is much higher

Comment: I think you should post solution to your problem from issue you have opened so this question won't be left unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

The project leader of LXC, LXD and LXCFS answer the question [here](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3860).

> This iterates over every single fd number up to RLIMIT_NOFILE, closing them all one by one, regardless of whether the fd actually does exist.
>
> On a normal system, this will be capped at 1024 as the most comment NOFILE limit. In LXD containers, we have it bumped to a much higher value, causing it to take longer.

So maybe it is better to use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module on a lxd container.